# Writing php form inputs to txt file

Tags: php, html, forms

I have this php form below which returns (displays) a simple calculation when submitted.  What i want to do now is to also submit the two inputs (height, weight) and result (function calculation) to a text file.  But i also dont want the path of the text file displayed.  Ideally i would like a new line added to the text file (separated by ;) for each time the form is submitted.

```html
<html>

<?php
function bmi($height, $weight) {
    $height = floatval($height);
    $weight = floatval($weight);
    return $weight / ($height * $height);
}
?>

<head>


    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <h4>BMI</h4>
    <input id="height" name="height" type="text" placeholder="height in meters or feet" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['height']) ? $_POST['height'] : ''; ?>" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input id="weight" name="weight" type="text" placeholder="weight in kgs or lbs" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['weight']) ? $_POST['weight'] : ''; ?>" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    <?php if (!empty($_POST['height']) && !empty($_POST['weight'])) : ?>

    <p id="result">Your score is <?php echo bmi($_POST['height'], $_POST['weight']); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"But i also dont want the path of the text file displayed"_? Displayed where? On the page? In your code?

Answer (score 2):

you can add line to same file when you [fopen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) with `a` mode you can fine more php fopen mode in [hear](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

```
<?php
    function bmi($height, $weight) {
        $height = floatval($height);
        $weight = floatval($weight);
        $result = $weight / ($height * $height);
        $data_file = fopen("data_file.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $txt = $height.";".$weight.";".$result."\n";
        fwrite($data_file,$txt);
        fclose($data_file);
        return $result;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: A good answer includes a proper explanation of the solution, like what problem does it solve and how/why.

Comment: thanx I will do it next time

Comment: _Suggestion:_ Instead of using `fopen()`, `fwrite()` and `fclose()`, you can do it all in one single call: `file_put_contents($theFilename, $theContent, FILE_APPEND);`.

Comment: Thank you, this works well.  Do you know what the memory management is like?  For example, what happens if the file is open and someone else tries to submit the form?

Comment: @RyanJamesHardy [ref this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016784/multiple-users-write-to-the-same-file-at-the-same-time-using-php)